# Windows 7 sees HDD as removable drive and is unable to access data

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, bios

I have recently bought a new computer and moved my old HDD (used for data storage), however Windows 7 sees it as removable drive and I cannot access any data on it.

```
Motherboard:              Asus Z170 Sabertooth Mark S Intel Z170 (Socket 1151) DDR4 ATX
Primary disk (SSD 500GB): Samsung 960 EVO Polaris 500GB M.2 2280 PCI-e 3.0 x4 NVMe
Storage disk (HDD 1TB):   Western Digital WD1001FALS-00J7B1
```

I have found many articles saying to switch off AHCI and hot plug in bios, however none of this helped.

---

### **This is how it looks like in Windows 7:**

[image: Windows 7 - Computer]
[image: Windows 7 - Device Manager]
[image: Windows 7 - Disk Management]

---

### **And this is how it looks in BIOS:**

[image: Bios - PCH Storage Configuration]
[image: Bios - HDD SMART Information]
[image: Bios - boot]

---

### **Other information:**

- The system says that disk driver is up to date (despite being dated 2006)
- I have no "eject drive" icon in the system tray (many articles I found mention this and focus on how to remove the icon rather than fixing the actual problem)
- I am wondering whether it could be a problem that I previously used this drive on Windows 7 Ultimate, while now I am on Windows 7 Professional
- I don't want any hot swap, this disk will be plugged in permanently and never removed

---

I am really out of ideas so any suggestions appreciated. If I missed any important information, please let me know and I will update the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only have two fixed disks connected to your computer, but Disk Management shows three drives. Are you *sure* your data drive is Disk 2 and not the Disk 0 shown in DM?

I think your drive is disk 0, in which case the problem is due to the fact your disk is a **Dynamic** disk (versus Simple) that's foreign to your machine. Notice in your screen shot of Disk Management the yellow bang next to the disk. I believe you can right-click the volume in DM and "import" the foreign disk and Windows should start recognizing the drive properly.

Comment: Thanks! That was it! I can still see that removable drive D: though... I is it related to the fact that it's dynamic disk? I am starting to think that it might be easier to just format this drive into a single basic partition, because I remember messing around creating dynamic disk long time ago...

Comment: My guess is that removable drive is coming from your Canon MP640. Disconnect that and see if it goes away.

Comment: You are right, that was the printer. I thought I checked that already... Anyway, once again thanks a lot :)

Comment: @JaroslawPawlak My pleasure